# Jekyll: How do I change the coloring scheme of inline code written in Markdown?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I don't mean syntax highlighting in code blocks but rather inline code like:
`this is an inline code`. I think it might have to do with the `_sass` folder css files, but I can't find a specific code in this [repository](https://github.com/PanosSakkos/personal-jekyll-theme/tree/71fb618a7ae31134efa024c1a16bafc2f5da8113) I forked that would change the coloring scheme. Is there a way I could replicate GitHub or StackOverflow inline coloring scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Jekyll markdown processor adds this HTML around inline code: `<code class="highlighter-rouge">code example</code>` (assuming you're using rouge).

For code blocks with ```` ```language-name ````, you get spans which you can style like this:

```
<div class="language-coffeescript highlighter-rouge">
  <pre class="highlight">
    <code>
      <span class="na">paginate_multiple</span>
      <span class="o">:</span>
      <span class="o">-</span>
      <span class="na">paginate</span>
      <span class="o">:</span>
      <span class="mi">3</span>
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Single ` marks for inline code doesn't output the spans with classes so it can't be styled.